# Handling ink In Microsoft.ink sdk

Tags: c#, tablet-pc, microsoft.ink

I am working on microsoft ink sdk. or the tablet pc using C#
   I have some strokes which i want to modify mathematically. in GIF format or ISF format I don't know how to retrieve the pressure information of the modified stroke. The other way if          I store the stroke in point form the pressure information is lost already. 
   What to do to get the pressure values for the modified stroke and in which format to handle ink.

Comment: It nearly always helps to post some code with your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The pressure values are stored in the fourth channel in the ISF data files. http://sourceforge.net/projects/inkmltk/ use the ISF to InkML converter and then open the file  in a text editor